# jQuery differentiate between click() and dblclick()

Tags: jquery, html, web, web-applications

I'm making a simple tic tac toe game for two players using jQuery. I want to insert "X" when user clicks and "O" when double clicks. This is what I used

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".tic").click(function(){
            $(this).append("X");
        });
        $(".tic").dblclick(function(){
            $(this).append("O");
        });
    });
```

When a user double clicks a "X" and then "O" is displayed.

Comment: There is a double click handler for jQuery, can't You use it? See here https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/ :).

Comment: Care to share a JSFiddle? Or explain a bit more? Is this not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand your problem. Your code is working as it is meant to, i.e. appending X on the first click, then O on the second click, but is not clearing... so you end up with XO.

If you correct your code to replace the text of the clicked `.tac` then it will overwrite the previous value. Here's a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ojtramp/j0ksqtep/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tic").click(function(){
        $(this).text("X");
    });
    $(".tic").dblclick(function(){
        $(this).text("O");
    });
});
```

---

**Alternatively just check the value of the text and cycle through blank, X, O.** This is probably a nicer experience for the player while keeping the functionality of double-clicking assigning 'O'.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tic").click(function(){
        if ($(this).text() == "" ) {
           $(this).text("X");
        } else if ( $(this).text() == "X" ) {
           $(this).text("O");
        } else {
           $(this).text("");
        }
    });
});
```

Let me know if this isn't actually your issue.